# An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'local_config_apple_cc'

Tags: mediapipe

On Mac OS, I get the following error when trying to run the *"Hello World!"* in C++ example.
It says there is no repository local_config_apple_cc
Is this something wrong with my PC settings?
Could you tell me why I am getting this error.

```
export GLOG_logtostderr=1
 bazel run --define MEDIAPIPE_DISABLE_GPU=1 \
    mediapipe/examples/desktop/hello_world:hello_world

INFO: Repository local_config_apple_cc instantiated at:
  /Users/a/mediapipe/WORKSPACE:117:31: in <toplevel>
  /private/var/tmp/_bazel_a/b0e6781141dc25d9d28cb801347dce96/external/build_bazel_rules_swift/swift/extras.bzl:35:31: in swift_rules_extra_dependencies
  /private/var/tmp/_bazel_a/b0e6781141dc25d9d28cb801347dce96/external/build_bazel_apple_support/lib/repositories.bzl:49:23: in apple_support_dependencies
  /private/var/tmp/_bazel_a/b0e6781141dc25d9d28cb801347dce96/external/build_bazel_apple_support/crosstool/setup.bzl:59:23: in apple_cc_configure
Repository rule _apple_cc_autoconf defined at:
  /private/var/tmp/_bazel_a/b0e6781141dc25d9d28cb801347dce96/external/build_bazel_apple_support/crosstool/setup.bzl:44:37: in <toplevel>
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'local_config_apple_cc':
   Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_a/b0e6781141dc25d9d28cb801347dce96/external/build_bazel_apple_support/crosstool/setup.bzl", line 39, column 39, in _apple_cc_autoconf_impl
        if not configure_osx_toolchain(repository_ctx):
    File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_a/b0e6781141dc25d9d28cb801347dce96/external/build_bazel_apple_support/crosstool/osx_cc_configure.bzl", line 160, column 21, in configure_osx_toolchain
        _compile_cc_file(repository_ctx, libtool_check_unique_src_path, "libtool_check_unique")
    File "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_a/b0e6781141dc25d9d28cb801347dce96/external/build_bazel_apple_support/crosstool/osx_cc_configure.bzl", line 82, column 13, in _compile_cc_file
        fail(out_name + " failed to generate. Please file an issue at " +
Error in fail: libtool_check_unique failed to generate. Please file an issue at https://github.com/bazelbuild/apple_support/issues with the following:
return code 1, stderr: In file included from /private/var/tmp/_bazel_a/b0e6781141dc25d9d28cb801347dce96/external/build_bazel_apple_support/crosstool/libtool_check_unique.cc:15:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/cstdlib:85:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/stdlib.h:93:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:62:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:807:2: error: Unsupported architecture
#error Unsupported architecture
 ^
In file included from
```

I tried bazel clean but it didn't work.

```
bazel clean --expunge
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to run the following command after updating Xcode.

```
$ sudo xcodebuild -license accept
```